# Android: Positioning Action Items on the left of the Action Bar

Tags: android

[image]
Hello everyone,

The first two pictures from the top is currently what I have. The arrow changes images when you click it. I want to make the arrow(action item) closer to the title(sort by) due to design requirements. I have tried to add blank action items to push the arrow over closer to the title but will not work to the various screen sizes.I also realize that the action bar is quite limited as you can only add action items to the right of the action bar.

I gave an example by displaying the bottom two pictures. As you can see the arrow is close to the Chinese title.

Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated as I am quite stuck. Thanks in advance !

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: How have you implemented this arrow?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I implemeneted this arrow by adding it to the menu, just like any regular action item.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to tell what the Chinese app is doing via **`uiautomatorviewer`**. Possibilities include:

- They are using the logo, where the Chinese characters and the arrow are both part of the graphic image. [See `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayUseLogoEnabled%28boolean%29).
- They have disabled the title and are using a custom navigation view. [See `setCustomView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View,%20android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams%29).

Comment: Hey CommonsWare, with your experience and knowledge which path would you take. I dont know if this is possible but can you add the arrow image somehow to the title of the action bar? I have also thought about making the title almost like an clickable image view but that causes re-sizing issues. It is weird because the chinese app logo/arrow covers the entire empty space.

Comment: Currently with my set up and the addition of the logo would it look like this from left to right -> 1.navigation drawer 2. title 3. logo(which is the arrow button)

Comment: @RyanCW: "but can you add the arrow image somehow to the title of the action bar?" -- not really. "It is weird because the chinese app logo/arrow covers the entire empty space" -- that would suggest they are going with the custom view option. With regards to your second comment, the logo would either be to the left of the title or replace the title (I forget which).

Comment: @RyanCW: "which path would you take" -- since I don't know what you're trying to achieve, I cannot really answer that. Visually, it feels like drop-down list navigation is the right answer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown